# Microsoft Teams Connector (Questions)

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm trying to figure out the concept of the MS Teams Connectors.
I've created an Incoming Webhook and a ticketing system is sending notifications in the form of "MessageCard" to a specific channel - so far, so good.

If I want to add buttons to this MessageCard, so if an user want to close a specific ticket, how the authentication to the ticket system can be handled?

I've checked and saw that there are "Connectors" for a lot of products. For example there is "Wunderlist" Connector. Once you configure it, it asks for a login and once you actually log-in - you get a list of task and blabla .. etc.

I created a connector, configured manifest.json, sideloaded it in MS Teams and so on .. but in the end I didn't see where exactly I can develop/configure the "login part".

Any help is appreciated!

Here is a screenshot from my demo connector:
[image]

While here is a screenshot from Wunderlist Connector:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sample connector here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-connector-github. That may be enough to get you going.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks a lot for helping me out. I will take a look at what you've shared!